# windows file sorting in a directory

Tags: windows, sorting

I'm just programming some functions concerning sorting files in a windows directory (windows 7).
While testing I found out, that if you have two files:

a3s.txt
  a-s.txt

Windows does NOT put the "a-s.txt" to the first place, although "-" has ASCII code 45 and "3" has ASCII code 51.

This only happens in windows explorer, it does not happen in windows command shell.

Why is this?

Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT:
This is not a duplicate question.
In the other postings they talk about situations, when the file names contain numbers. But here the problem also happens when you have "a_s.txt" and "a-s.txt". Furthermore the problem does not only happen in Windows 7, but also on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Same answer. Explorer uses a non-lexicographic sort that is believed to be more intuitive for users. That affects not only numbers, but also symbols. It is very unclear to me what your ***programming*** question is. This just looks like a question about using Windows Explorer, which would be off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  MSFT uses a custom sorting algorithm in Windows Explorer that they believe is more intuitive for most users.  For more information and a brief history, see [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh475812.aspx).  The article describes that the custom sorting began with Windows XP, which was the precursor to Server 2003.

> "This is not a duplicate question"

The symptoms are different, but the root cause is the same.  Windows Explorer does not use lexicographical sorting.

Comment: It may be a custom algorithm, but it is not proprietary or unique to Explorer. Explorer calls the [`StrCmpLogicalW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947.aspx) function, and so can your application. Similar flags exist for the `CompareStringEx` function, which has more predictable behavior and can be relied upon across multiple versions.